# heap-buffer-overflow on NSData converting

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I've noticed interesting behavior of AddressSanitizer in XCode 8. In one case it lead to catching breakpoint: *AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address* but I really dont understand why:

```
    char * buffer = malloc(length);
    memset(buffer, 0, length);
    [output getBytes:buffer
              length:length];
    stringOutput = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]; // here is crash
```

same to:

```
stringOutput = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:output.bytes];
```

But everything fine for cases:

```
stringOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also after some experiments I've seen that if we add '0' to end of the buffer everything will fine:

```
char * buffer = malloc(length + 1);
memset(buffer, 0, length + 1);
[output getBytes:buffer
          length:length];
stringOutput = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer];
```

This behavior unexpectable for me because I've used *stringWithUTF8String:output.bytes* dozen times on live code without any problems... So where I'm wrong?

Comment: `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]` reads the bytes until a NUL-terminator is found. If there is no zero byte in the allocated and filled memory, undefined memory will be read.

Comment: but why stringOutput = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:output.bytes]; lead to crash? I assume that Cocoa smart enough for resolve such problems in that case?

Comment: Because that method *cannot know* now many bytes are defined or valid.

Comment: You are telling Cocoa that there are bytes with trailing zero bytes. You are lying to it. Cocoa is very trusting. You lie to it, you get what you deserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]` takes a `const char *` as an argument,
and reads bytes, starting the given memory location, until a terminating `0` byte
is found. **If there is no `0` byte within the allocated and written-to
memory, it will continue to read undefined memory,** or even from
invalid memory locations. The method has *no information* about
how many bytes starting at the given pointer are defined.

On the other hand `[[NSString alloc] initWithData: encoding:]`
takes a `NSData` argument (which comprises both a pointer to the data *and* a length) and reads exactly from the bytes defined by
that object.

Comment: Cool, thank you Martin. Just never thought that it might be problem in that place...